# Неправильный JAVA_HOME в hadoop для spark-shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark

У меня был установлен hadoop. Нужно было установить spark 3.5.0. Я настроил переменные env в моем .bashrc :

````
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11.0.20.1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
#Pig location 
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/pig-0.17.0 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/pig-0.17.0/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/conf

export SPARK_HOME=/home/hadoop/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3``` 
вылезает ошибка /home/hadoop/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11.0.20.1/bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/hadoop/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
````